# DNS Prefetch subdomains

Tags: dns, prefetch

I have a question regarding dns prefetch of internal subdomains.
Say i have a site spread ower several subdomains:

- www.domain.com
- images.domain.com
- shop.domain.com

Will it give me any perfomance to do a prefetch of those subdomains?
Like this:

```
 <link href="//images.domain.com" rel="dns-prefetch" />
 <link href="//shop.domain.com" rel="dns-prefetch" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've determined that it would be useful to use `dns-prefetch` for some resources, there is no difference between a subdomain vs a completely independent domain in that case so I would use prefetch.

Each subdomain can contain completely different addresses, cnames, etc so from the perspective of the browser they are as different as any other domain.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep my dns-prefetch